# Shopware - Pass $sUserLoggedIn-Variable to Widget

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

i am currently having a problem with requesting if a user is logged in, in a Shopware-Widget.
I need to do this since some Elements on the Emotion-Pages should be hidden if the user is not logged in. What i just did was to alter the code in the component_html.tpl to something like this:

```
{if $Data.cms_title|substr:0:1 == "_"}
    {assign var="private" value=true}
{else}
    {assign var="private" value=false}
{/if}


{if $Data.cms_title}
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>{$Data.cms_title|substr:1}</h3>
        {if $private and $sUserLoggedIn}<p>This block is private</p>{/if}
    </div>
{/if}
{$Data.text}
```

Unfortunately Shopware does not pass the template-variables (in this case $sUserLoggedIn) to the widgets by default, and i have no clue how to solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated :)
regards

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to inject the DI Container to your class.

After that you have access to the Sesson via : `$session = $this->container->get('session');`

Now you can do something like that :

```
$view->assign('isUserLoggedIn', !empty($session->sUserId)); or
$view->assign('isUserLoggedIn', !empty($session->offsetGet("sUserId"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to make `$sUserLoggedIn` a global variable? You can find a tutorial in the [Shopware docs](http://community.shopware.com/Globale-Variablen-im-Template-verwenden_detail_938.html).

Comment: best and simple way. Just for info, to make a variable global you just need to add `scope="global"` while adding a variable,

Answer (score -1):

This is ugly, but shopware does it in it's own code. Well, with shopware almost everything looks like a hack.
In my plugin's bootstrap I do:

```
$view->assign('isUserLoggedIn', !empty(Shopware()->Session()['sUserId']));
```